# SSIS Package - return code of 2?

Tags: ssis, etl

Package log shows no errors at all, just performance warnings and actually runs/finishes correctly, yet returns "DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_COMPLETION (2)"

According to the documentation ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx)) this is not a documented return code. I really need this package to return a code of 0. Has anyone seen this before? This is a 2008 SSIS package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForceExecutionResult was set to Completion instead of None.